# How to set these constraints programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Currently I have my viewcontroller as below

```
--highestView-- 
--topView-- 
--tableView--
```

I would like to make the `topView` dissappear when I scroll down which means `tableView` will be exactly below the `highestView`.

So upon scrolling up, I would like them to go back to original view which is like above.

My code is as below:-

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{

    CGFloat scrollPos = self.tableView.contentOffset.y ;

    if(scrollPos >= self.currentOffset ){
        //Fully hide your toolbar
        [UIView animateWithDuration:2.25 animations:^{
            self.topView.hidden = YES;
            self.topViewTopConstraint.active = NO;
            self.theNewConstraint2.active = NO;
            self.theNewConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.tableView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.highestView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0];
            self.theNewConstraint.active = YES;

        }];
    } else {
        //Slide it up incrementally, etc.
        self.theNewConstraint.active = NO;
        self.topView.hidden = NO;
        self.topViewTopConstraint.active = YES;
        self.theNewConstraint2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.tableView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.topView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0];
        self.theNewConstraint2.active = YES;



        //self.topView.hidden = NO;
    }
}
```

Scrolling down works exactly like how I want but scrolling up fails. Currently, the `topView` shows up at the back of `tableView` upon scrolling up. How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

set the height cosntraint for your topView and make it 0 when you want to hide it!

Look into using [Masonry](https://github.com/SnapKit/Masonry) for applying constraints.

For adding height constraint:

```
[toppView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    make. mas_height.equalTo(100); //just make this 0 when you want to hide the topView
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using XIB constraints.
`HeightView` <-> `TopView` <-> `TableView`  these three views are connected to each other with `Vertical Space` and `Bottom Space` constraints.

Then add height constraint to `TopView` and make it's `IBOutlet` as:

```
@IBOutlet weak var topViewHeightCon: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

And then your own code can reused as:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
  CGFloat scrollPos = self.tableView.contentOffset.y;
  if(scrollPos >= self.currentOffset ){
    topViewHeightCon.constant = 0
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
  } else {
    topViewHeightCon.constant = originalHeight
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
  }
}
```